# Angular form gives an error saying "_co.sevice is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

Im trying to send data to a firebase project from an angular form, where I get this particular error.

This is the html part of the component that contains the form

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="off"> 

              <div class="form-row">
                <div class="input-group form-group-no-border col-lg-6">
                  <input type="text" name=FirstName #FirstName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="sevice.formData.FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name..." required />
                </div>
                <div class="input-group form-group-no-border input-lg col-lg-6">
                  <input type="text" name=LastName #LastName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="sevice.formData.LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name..." required />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="input-group form-group-no-border input-lg">
                <input type="text" name=Email #Email="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="sevice.formData.Email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address..." required />
              </div>
              <div class="input-group form-group-no-border input-lg">
                  <input type="password" name=Password #Password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="sevice.formData.Password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control" required />
              </div>
              <div class="input-group form-group-no-border input-lg">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Re-Enter Password..." class="form-control" required />
              </div>

              <div class="footer text-center">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-round btn-lg btn-info"> Get Started</button>
              </div>  

            </form>
```

And this is the typescript file of that component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../Shared/authentication.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.scss']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service : AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  resetForm(form? : NgForm){
    if(form!=null){
      form.resetForm();
      this.service.formData={
        FirstName : '',
        LastName : '', 
        Email : '',
        Password : '',
      }
    }
  }

}
```

And then this's the service code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Authentication } from './authentication.model'; 

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {
  formData :  Authentication;

  constructor() { }
}
```

and finally the service model class

```
export class Authentication {
    FirstName : string ;
    LastName : String ;
    Email : string ;
    Password : string ;
}
```

Im sorry if im unclear. It would be great, if somebody can help me to solve this.

Comment: You cannot use service on template. Just create a new Authentication object on your component and set it to your service on form submit.

Comment: Yeah that worked well with it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the constructor of your component, you are setting the service as a private variable, so you won't be able to access it from the template unless you set it to public. That's for one.
Now if you look at the error, you will also notice you misspelled service in the template, you wrote sevice instead. I think it should work if you fix those two things.

As it's been mentioned in the comments, I also don't thing it's a good practice to expose the service like that either. You should collect the data (email, password and so on) in the component, and then send it to the service with a click event or something of that fashion.

Comment: thank you very much. Also I created a new Object of Authentication and with fixing the errors you figured out, it worked well. Thanks again